# Google's RDFa breadcrumbs for home and current page?

Tags: html, schema.org, breadcrumbs, google-rich-snippets, rdfa

As I couldn't find a proper RDFa example anywhere, I thought I'd ask a question here. On [Google's page](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb) there are examples of breadcrumbs, using either Microdata or RDFa markup. When you click on "See Markup" under "RDFa" next to "Example 2" you'll see an example of markup for this particular type of breadcrumb (As far as I know, images in breadcrumbs are optional, so I got rid of them):

```html
<ol vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="BreadcrumbList">
  <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
    <a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="https://example.com/books">
      <span property="name">Books</span>
    </a>
    <meta property="position" content="1">
  </li>
  ›
  <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
    <a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="https://example.com/books/sciencefiction">
      <span property="name">Science Fiction</span>
    </a>
    <meta property="position" content="2">
  </li>
  ›
  <li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
    <a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="https://example.com/books/sciencefiction/awardwinnders">
      <span property="name">Award Winners</span>
    </a>
    <meta property="position" content="3">
  </li>
</ol>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't say anything about Home and Current Page breadcrumb, so I'm not sure how to construct it.

To be more exact with my question, what `property` and `typeof` attribute to use for home and current page? Shall I just use the first link from above example for Home Page without changing anything in the markup and for Current Page only omit the link, as it's not really needed so it would look like this?:

```html
<li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
  <a property="item" typeof="WebPage" href="https://example.com">
    <span property="name">Home Page</span>
  </a>
  <meta property="position" content="1">
</li>

   // Above is for Home, below is for Current. I omitted items 2 and 3 which are positioned somwhere in between..

<li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
  <span property="name">Current Page</span>
  <meta property="position" content="4">
</li>
```

Comment: Why do you want to treat the home page and the current page in a special way? Why not just add them in the same way as "Books", "Science Fiction" etc.?

Comment: @unor As for the Current Page I don't really need a link for it, that's why I didnt wrap it with link, but can it be done this way?. I wasn't sure about Home page; in the example above I treat it exactly as "Books", "Scence Fiction", etc but is it a right path to walk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to treat the entry for the home page differently, so yes, provide it just like the other items.

If you want to provide an entry for the current page without showing a link, you still might want to specify the `WebPage` type. This would also allow you to provide the current page’s URL without adding a user-visible link to the page.

```html
<li property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
  <span property="item" typeof="WebPage" resource="/current-page.html">
    <span property="name">Current Page</span>
  </span>
  <meta property="position" content="4">
</li>
```

Instead of the `a` element, it uses a `span` element.
The `resource` attribute (from RDFa) specifies the URI of the item (without creating a hyperlink).

Comment: Everything seems to be perfectly valid to me. Thanks for your effort! Best regards!